# Sperm donation - where should I donate?

Tags: obstetrics, sex, reproduction

I recently discover sperm banks pay for sperm donation all over the world.

I'm an Italian citizen. 
Which are the best countries in Europe to donate semen?

In terms of:

- Guarantees I won't have to pay child support nor any other expenses
- Having no legal duties/linking to the children
- Get paid the most for every single donation

In a few words, going to the lab, donate sperm, collect money and go back to my normal life.

Comment: In many cases, they will require you to have one child first, make a spermogram etc. This is not as easy as you may think it is